# How to override Admob reward ads timer text in Android

Tags: android, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I am able to display Google AdMob Reward Ads.

Now I want to override the timer text in the Ads. See the below image in which I have highlighted the text to change.
[image]

Is there any way to override it?. I have tried to set the `customData` but failed!!.

Following is my Kotlin code :

```
var mRewardedVideoAd  = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(activity) as RewardedVideoAd
mRewardedVideoAd.rewardedVideoAdListener = this
mRewardedVideoAd.customData="Watch TV in full screen with in"
mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(getString(R.string.REWARD_ADS_ID),
AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("A55D26BCECE9CE60D47A8D8F7BBE8015").build())
```

Comment: I don't think you can replace the whole text. You may be able to draw over it though.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, it is not possible. I got an official reply from Google. Please check the below link

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-admob-ads-sdk/How$20to$20override$20Admob$20reward%7Csort:date/google-admob-ads-sdk/c20Rnh_hZ-Y/3DwOOVhKBwAJ